# Create a bridge inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, bridge

I have a docker container running on my computer. I want to use a program inside the container that needs to have a network bridge to a virtual network interface (a bridge between the container and the program running inside the container).

For information, the container is using a bridge to have network access (between the container and the host).

The container have an eth0 interface that have network access.
I'm trying to create a bridge interface br0 and a virtual interface veth0.

To do this, I'm editing `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
pre-up ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 promisc
post-down ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 -promisc

pre-up ip tuntap add dev veth0 mode tap user louis
pre-up ifconfig veth0 0.0.0.0 promisc
post-down ip tuntap del dev veth0 mode tap

bridge_ports eth0 veth0
```

Then, execute the following commands:

```
brctl addbr br0
ifconfig eth0 down && ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig br0 up
service network-manager restart
```

After a `ifconfig`, the `br0` interface is showing but not the `veth0`.
However, when I do the same thing in a Virtual Machine the `veth0` is present.

For information, the container is run with the `--privileged` option. The container is running Ubuntu 16.04, same for my host computer.

I hope I have put all the informations needed, please let me know if not.